# css issue with the xhtml code on internet explorer 7 and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having issue with my `css` in `IE7` and `IE8`

I m using the following code for my input box but the background image is not get displayed
on internet explorer 7 and 8.The image is getting displayed on all other browsers.

```
.search input[type="submit"] {
    background: url(../images/search_button.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    float: right;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One *unknown/wrong* value of a property makes the whole property *invalide*.

IE 7 and 8 do not know `rgba` so the whole `background` is not applied.

To solve that problem you could split move the `rgba` to `background-color`:

```
.search input[type="submit"] {
    background: url(../images/search_button.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    float: right;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 40px;
}
```